# Pass object to DROOLS

Tags: java, drools

I am very new to DROOLS.
I am working with Activiti-Explorer and I need DROOLS for decision making. I have created an Instance object of the class and added the data fetched from the API.

```
LoanApplicant loanApplicant = new LoanApplicant();
loanApplicant.setUserID(obj.getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("ownership_details").getInt("user_id"));
loanApplicant.setApplicantName(obj.getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("ownership_details").getString("name"));
```

Similarly I have set few more fields in to the class object and then I have set it in to Java delegate variable arg0 to Activiti memory

```
arg0.setVariable("loanApplication", loanApplicant);
```

And Similarly, as DROOLS decisions outputs are further required, I have created an Output java file recording its decisions.

Output java file: RulesOutput.java: -

```
private String testValue = null;
public String getTestValue(){
    return this.getTestValue();
}
public void setTestValue(String testValue){
    this.testValue = testValue;
}
```

Similarly to loanApplicant, I have set this class in to memory:

```
arg0.setVariable("RulesOutput", new RulesOutput());
```

Now I am passing these fields from Process BPMN Diagram to Drools Task Work Step.

[image]

This is my DROOLS .drl file:

```
import com.LOS.*;
rule "FLS_1"
when
    $loanApplication : loanApplication(age >= 20 && age < 60)
    $rulesOutput : RulesOutput (isApproved == false || isApproved == true)
then
    rulesOutput.setAgeScore(100);
```

end

Now the **Problem**: 
I am getting `Unable to resolve ObjectType` even though I have passed all the required objects to DROOLS.
Error Log:

```
06:39:47,288 [http-bio-8480-exec-15] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer  - Processing resource RuleSet_1.drl
06:39:47,288 [http-bio-8480-exec-15] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer  - Processing resource LOS_1.bpmn20.xml'
06:39:47,645 [http-bio-8480-exec-15] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.rules.RulesDeployer  - Processing resource RuleSet_1.drl
06:39:47,702 [http-bio-8480-exec-15] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.rules.RulesDeployer  - Processing resource LOS_1.bpmn20.xml
06:39:47,704 [http-bio-8480-exec-15] ERROR org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl  - Unable to resolve ObjectType '$loanApplication' : [Rule name='FLS_1']
06:39:47,704 [http-bio-8480-exec-15] ERROR org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl  - Unable to resolve ObjectType '$RulesOutput' : [Rule name='FLS_1']
06:39:47,704 [http-bio-8480-exec-15] ERROR org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl  - Rule Compilation error : [Rule name='FLS_1']
[http-bio-8480-exec-15] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer  - Processing resource RuleSet_1.drl
[http-bio-8480-exec-15] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer  - Processing resource LOS_1.bpmn20.xml
[http-bio-8480-exec-15] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.rules.RulesDeployer  - Processing resource RuleSet_1.drl
[http-bio-8480-exec-15] INFO  org.activiti.engine.impl.rules.RulesDeployer  - Processing resource LOS_1.bpmn20.xml
[http-bio-8480-exec-15] ERROR org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl  - Unable to resolve ObjectType '$loanApplication' : [Rule name='FLS_1']
[http-bio-8480-exec-15] ERROR org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl  - Unable to resolve ObjectType '$RulesOutput' : [Rule name='FLS_1']
[http-bio-8480-exec-15] ERROR org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl  - Rule Compilation error : [Rule name='FLS_1']
com/LOS/Rule_FLS_1842423443.java (7:323) : \RulesOutput cannot be resolved
```

I am stuck here for almost 2 days. Please any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Are you sure that the DRL code is exactly what you have posted when you get these errors= What are the packages of classes `loanApplication` and `RulesOutput`? Why is there a difference between `$rulesOutput` and `rulesOutput`? What errors do you get when you omit `$loanApplication`?

Comment: `loanApplication` and `RulesOutput` are in the package `com.LOS.approc.dao`. Because of errors I was facing, I  included the complete `com.LOS.*` package. If i understood correctly, `$loanApplication` and `rulesOutput` are the variables to store the result of the expression after **`:`**. So if I omit `$loanApplication`, then I am just removing the variable and hence no change in errors. I had removed `$loanApplication` and still the same. For some reason, `${loanApplication}` and `${Rules}` which I had passed through process diagram, are not being parsed.

Comment: can you try importing this package com.LOS.approc.dao.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import com.LOS.*;
```

If loanApplication and RulesOutput are in package com.LOS.approc.dao, you have to use

```
import com.LOS.approc.dao.*;
```

although individual imports are usually preferred. (Talking about style: you should stick to conventions and use first letter in uppercase for class names.

```
$loanApplication : loanApplication(age >= 20 && age < 60)
```

If you don't need to refer to this object, a binding (`$loanApplication:`) can be omitted.

```
    $rulesOutput : RulesOutput (isApproved == false || isApproved == true)
then
    rulesOutput.setAgeScore(100); ## missing dollar
```

If you use `$rulesOutput` as the name for the binding variable, you have to stick with that name. The `$` is part of the (Java) name of the variable, not a macro expansion operator as your remark on trying `${loanApplication}` and `${Rules}` suggests.

Comment: Thank You. For some reason, importing complete package was not working `com.LOS.*` instead had to import individually.